# Can the UN charge/"fine" Mali for equipment lost due to movement restrictions imposed by the Mali junta?

Tags: united-nations, finance, peacekeeping, mali

[Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/world/africa/un-retreat-mali-disarray-violence-surges-2023-11-03/):

> The U.N. has acknowledged difficulties with its departure. MINUSMA said in statements that it has been forced to destroy equipment including vehicles, ammunition and generators that its forces couldn't evacuate after the government imposed restrictions on moving them. Mission spokesperson Fatoumata Sinkoun Kaba told Reuters that millions of dollars of kit has been lost.

So, since the UN alleges the losses are due to the way the Mali junta restricted MINUSMA movements, can the UN "get their money back" in some way? Like up the Mali [dues](https://www.un.org/en/ga/about/art19.shtml) to participate in UNGA votes or something like that?